# Complicated pattern separation on one column of dataframe, while keeping original columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like specific separations of values within my column to display the first word and the number along with its **'T'** value. I would like the first **'word' that is separated by '-' and its #T value.** It is **tricky because some of the #T values are separated by '-',** while **others are separated by '_'**
ex.  **-12T**  in one of the values , as well as **_14T** in another value

**Data:**

```
type                                                 free      use    total

Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.A                 10        10       20
Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.E                 5         1        6
Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.C                 1         4        5
Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.A                 2         1        1
Happy-HAP-HA-R650-570A-90T_version-v.A               10        0        10
Kind-KIN-KI-T490-NET_14T-A.0                         7         4        3
Kind-KIN-KI-T490-NET_14T-A.0                         6         3        2
AY14.5-fyy-FY-R770-256G-6.4T-R1-v.A                  3         0        3
AY14.5-fyy-FY-R770-256G-6.4T-R1-v.A                  0         20       20
```

**Desired:**

```
    type                free    use  total
            
    Hello   12T         10      10   20
    Hello   12T         5       1    6
    Hello   50T         1       4    5
    Hello   50T         2       1    1
    Happy   90T         10      0    10
    Kind    14T         7       4    3
    Kind    14T         6       3    2
    AY14.5  6.4T        3       0    3
    AY14.5  6.4T        0       20   20
```

**Doing:**

```
df['type']=df['type'].str.extract('(\w+(?=[-AYY]))')+ " "+ df['type'].str.extract('(?<=0G-)(.*?)(?=\-|_)')
```

**This works below**, **however, only the column that is being transformed remains**. The other columns are not present:

```
import pandas as pd

def extract_value(s):
    regex = re.search(r'(^.+?)-.+?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?T)', s)
    if regex:
        first_word = regex.group(1)
        code = regex.group(2)
        return f'{first_word} {code}'
    return s


df.columns = ['type']
df['type'] = df[type'].apply(lambda x: extract_value(x))
```

However, this only extracts the values that have a certain pattern. How would I have this apply to the full sample set?

Any suggestion is appreciated, I am still troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! You can use this regular expression to capture everything you want in one go. I've included comments within the regular expression. To inform `re` of this, I pass the flag `re.X` which means this pattern is a "verbose" pattern and has comments in it that should be ignored when it comes to performing the actual matching.

```
import re

pattern = """
^([^-]+)-    # From the beginning of the string, capture all non-hyphen characters and stop at the first actual hyphen.
.+?          # Consume all characters up to the next capture group in this pattern
([\d.]+T)    # Capture all digits (including a literal period) that end with a "T".
""".strip()

extracted_df = df["type"].str.extract(pattern, flags=re.X)

print(extracted_df)
        0     1
0   Hello   12T
1   Hello   12T
2   Hello   50T
3   Hello   50T
4   Happy   90T
5    Kind   14T
6    Kind   14T
7  AY14.5  6.4T
8  AY14.5  6.4T
```

So now that we've extracted the relevant bits of information, we can go ahead and stick them together to overwrite the old `"type"` column:

```
df["type"] = extracted_df[0] + " " + extracted_df[1]

print(df)
          type  free  use  total
0    Hello 12T    10   10     20
1    Hello 12T     5    1      6
2    Hello 50T     1    4      5
3    Hello 50T     2    1      1
4    Happy 90T    10    0     10
5     Kind 14T     7    4      3
6     Kind 14T     6    3      2
7  AY14.5 6.4T     3    0      3
8  AY14.5 6.4T     0   20     20
```

As per usual with regular expressions, this may not capture all corner cases but I hope it clarified the approach of how to use regular expressions and capture groups to gather relevant bits of information out of a column.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['type'].str.extract(r'(^\w+.\d|^\w+)')+' '+df['type'].str.extract(r'(\d.\d+T|\d+T)')



     type      free  use  total
0    Hello 12T    10   10     20
1    Hello 12T     5    1      6
2    Hello 50T     1    4      5
3    Hello 50T     2    1      1
4    Happy 90T    10    0     10
5     Kind 14T     7    4      3
6     Kind 14T     6    3      2
7  AY14.5 6.4T     3    0      3
8  AY14.5 6.4T     0   20     20
```

Comment: only shows first column, not sure why. Thank you

Comment: `df['type']= df['type'].str.extract(r'(^\w+.\d|^\w+)')+' '+df['type'].str.extract(r'(\d.\d+T|\d+T)')`

Comment: Equate to `df['type']` and print df

Comment: Just about new year, smile!